# What's up with method(void) in Cpp?

Tags: c++

So I found this

```
public:
    ListElem(string s);
    
    string     getData(void) const;
    ListElem*  getNext(void) const;
    ListElem*  getPrev()     const;
```

Btw this is a snippet of a list in a header file written in cpp

Can someone tell me whats that "(void)" for? Where is the difference between methodName() and methodName(void)?

Comment: Looks like a relic of C, where there was a difference between those two signatures. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c) for more.

Comment: @NathanPierson _absolutely_ a duplicate, in my opinion... (And then Asteroids beats me to it)

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone tell me whats that "(void)" for? Where is the difference between methodName() and methodName(void)?

In C++, there is no difference.  Both are functions that take no parameters.

In C, only `functionName(void)` claims to take no parameters.  `functionName()` indicates that the parameter list isn't being specified.

It should also be noted that C++ does not recognize the term *method* to mean anything.  You are talking about *functions*.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `void foo()` is equal to `void foo(void)`, so they both mean that `foo` should take no arguments. You can use latter to highlight the lack of arguments, but they work pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

methodName() and methodName(void) both are same its just that you are telling compiler i dont want anything as a paramer if you dont write void then also it take void.

Both are same.